# Python script doesn't seem to execute from top to bottom

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, urllib2

I want to download images from a distant server based on their names (`http://mysite.com/id?id=abc1`, `http://mysite.com/id?id=abc2`, ...).

The dowloading part works, but since there might be a lot of files to download (sometimes more than 200), I want to add a label "Please wait" (Tkinter). The problem is that my label only appears when the download is complete, which is not very useful of course.

How can I get it to appear earlier?

```
from Tkinter import *
import urllib2
import time

window = Tk()
window.title('My Downloader')
photo=PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
labl = Label(window, image=photo)
labl.pack()
mainid = Label(window, text = 'Main id:')
mid = Entry(window)
complete = Label(window, text = 'download complete !')

def dl():
    right = Label (window, text ='downloading...Please wait')
    right.pack()
    time.sleep(2)
    i='10'

    while int(i) <= 100000 :
        if len(str(i))==1:
            i="0000"+str(i)
        elif len(str(i))==2:
            i="000"+str(i)
        elif len(str(i))==3:
            i="00"+str(i)
        elif len(str(i))==4:
            i="0"+str(i)

        url = 'http://mysite.com/id?recordID='+ str(mid.get())+str(i)

        try:
            dltest = urllib2.urlopen(url)            
            with open(str(mid.get())+str(i)+'.tiff', 'wb') as f:
                while True:
                    content = dltest.read()
                    if not content: break
                    f.write(content)                
        except urllib2.URLError:            
            if int(i)==10:
                wrong = Label (window, text ='wrong id ')
                wrong.pack()
                break
            else:                
                complete.pack()
                break                                       
        i=int(i)+10
dlbutton = Button(window, text =' Download!', command=dl)
mainid.pack()
mid.pack()
dlbutton.pack() 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `i="0"+str(i)` etc, consider using `url = 'http://mysite.com/id?recordID=%s%05d' % (mid.get(), i)`

Answer (score 2):

Just call window.update() after you set the label.

```
right = Label (window, text ='downloading...Please wait')
right.pack()
window.update()
```

But a better thing to do would be to thread the URL downloads. This can be a rather complex task, but will allow you to free up your GUI while you are downloading the files. Take a look at [this page](http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/multi-threading-python/) for how you might thread your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll have a look. I am particularly interested in threading because my gui seems to freeze during the download.

Comment: For any single threaded application that isn't handled very well, the GUI will freeze, no matter what programming language during something like a file copy. Definitely look into threading!